# Pass by reference in a stack

Tags: c, stack, pass-by-reference

I am trying to create a simple program where the idea of the task is to create a stack that can take in a set number of values for the array and be able to push and pop the values on command. I am having trouble getting to my pass around correctly. I do not think the values are even getting added to the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int push(int x, int st, int stack1[]);
int pop(int st, int stack1[]);
int main ()
{
    char stack1[10];
    int stmax = 5;
    int st = -1;
    int x;
    int choice;

        while (1) {
                printf("What would you like to do? \n1. Check Empty\n2. Check Full\n3. Push\n4. Pop\n5. show\n\n");
                scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                if(st = -1){
                        printf("Empty\n");
                }   else    {
                        printf("Not Full\n");
                        }

                break;
            case 2:
                if(st == stmax) {
                        printf("Full\n");
                }   else    {
                        printf("Not Full\n");
                        }

                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Enter a int to add to the stack:\n");
                scanf("%d", &x);
                push(x, st, stack1);
                break;
            case 4:
                pop(st, stack1);
                printf("%d", stack1[st]);
            default:

                break;
        }
    } return(0);
}

int pop(int st, int stack1[]) {
    int data;
    data = stack1[st];
    printf("%d", data);
    return(st);
}

int push(int x, int st, int stack1[]) {
    st ++;
    stack1[st]=x;
    return(st);
}
```

Comment: `if(st = -1){` : `=` typo as `==`. Also You need to update the `st`.

Comment: You are not updating `st` after `push` or `pop` but ignoring their return value.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @alk thanks am going to read this